# Getting DoubleClick data from Google Analytics exported to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-api, double-click-advertising

I have GA360 and I have exported raw Google Analytics data to BigQuery through the integration. I'm just wondering if the DCM dimensions and metrics are part of the export?

[Ideally these link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=doubleclick_campaign_manager)

I can't find them as part of the export, what would be the best way to access these dimensions for all my raw data? Core reporting API?

Comment: Have you explored the BigQuery Data Transfer Service? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfer/ a feature of this service is raw data exports from DCM into BigQuery in the same way your GA data is transferred.

Comment: Hi @BenP Yes this seems like the only option. I'm just worried there won't be anyway to link the data from GA and DCM together (no unique client id across the two systems, for example)

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to make some link. We were going to do this on UserID as passed to GA as a custom dimension, but as we do not use DCM we couldn't take this forward. Can say that the agency involved were confident of making a link, so I'd give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

This Google Analytics documentation page shows the [BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089) for the Google Analytics data that is exported to BigQuery. As you will see, the DoubleClick Campaign Manager (DCM) data is not part of the BigQuery export, unlike the DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP), which does appear (these are all the `hits.publisher.<DFP_METRIC>` metrics).

Therefore, as explained by @BenP in the comments, you may be interested in the BigQuery Data Transfer service, which does have a [feature for DoubleClick Campaign Manager Transfers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/doubleclick-campaign-transfer). Unfortunately, I am not an expert in Google Analytics or DCM, and therefore cannot add much relevant info to the process of linking both sets of data, but maybe you can try combining them yourself and then post a new question for that matter if you do not success in doing so.